# Restore Deleted Update List SCCM 2007

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I mistakenly deleted an large update list from my SCCM 2007 console.  Anyway to restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, short of recovering the database from a prior backup... the answer is no (and I do not recommend doing a DB recovery to get your list back).  It would be nice if SCCM gave you a dummy box before it blows away your update list :(

Unfortunately, you'll need to re-create your update list.

Of course, in the future, you can change the permissions on the update list so that you can't delete it.  That way, you'll need to explicitly give yourself delete permissions first, thus giving you an additional step for safety.